# Nginx Reverse Proxy and ZAP

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, zap

i'm trying to configure Nginx as reverse Proxy for my sec-tool (ZAP). I'm not sure about the configuration part. I think it should be something like that:

```
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name ZAP.domain.com;


    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://ZAP.domain.com;
    }
  }
```

As long as i know, ZAP operates with the port 8080, but i'm not sure what I've to insert in the "domain" part.

Does anyone have some clues here?

Thank you

Comment: Does ZAP.domain.com exist? Is ZAP bound to the IP that DNA entry resolves to?

Comment: It was just an example, I'm actually unsure about that parameter or what I should use instead

Comment: You should forward to where ZAP is listening.

Comment: @kingthorin so that means just the localhost:8080 right?